# Controller has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber? Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Всем добрый день, делаю свое первое приложение на Symfony 5

Столкнулась с проблемой при создании контроллера, при этом мне нужен именно контроллер, а не сервис

**Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: ""App\Controller\UploadFileController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?" at /vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php line 36**

Cоздала обычный контроллер с наследованием от  AbstractController, при создании я пользовалась командой **symfony console make:controller UploadFileController**

```
class UploadFileController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test-upload", name="app_test_upload")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Описала в конфигах значения, пробовала чистить кэш - не помогло

routes.yaml

```
testAction:
    path: /test-upload
    controller: App\Controller\UploadFileController::testAction
```

Comment: посмотрите, в services.yaml прописан сервис `App\Controller\:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в соответствующем **services.yaml** нужно прописать тег контроллера

```
    App\Controller\:
          resource: '../../Controller'
          tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```